# Openlayer Map mouse events on WxWidget WebView (UPDATED)

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm currently trying to integrate Openlayer map with the WxWidgets WebView and so far I'm able to get the map on the WebView perfectly but I do not receive the mouse clicks and move events.
The same webpage runs perfectly on Chrome and i receive all the events on the map, but on the WxWidgets WebView I can only get the mouse scroll events but no clicks and move.
Right now I have this test code where I can see that the webView receives the mouse events but the openlayer Map doesn't.

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {defaults as defaultControls} from 'ol/control';
import MousePosition from 'ol/control/MousePosition';
import {createStringXY} from 'ol/coordinate';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

var info = document.getElementById('info');
var mapinfo = document.getElementById('mapInfo');

var mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
  // be placed within the map.
  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
  undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});

var map = new Map({
  controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

var projectionSelect = document.getElementById('projection');
projectionSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  mousePositionControl.setProjection(event.target.value);
});

var precisionInput = document.getElementById('precision');
precisionInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var format = createStringXY(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  mousePositionControl.setCoordinateFormat(format);
});


function printMousePos(event) {
  document.getElementById("mouse_posX").innerHTML  = event.clientX;
    document.getElementById("mouse_posY").innerHTML   = event.clientY;
}
document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);




function tellPos(p){
  info.innerHTML = 'Position X : ' + p.pageX + '<br />Position Y : ' + p.pageY;
  mapinfo.innerHTML = map.getEventPixel(p);
  //mapinfo.innerHTML = map.dispatchEvent(p);
}
addEventListener('mousemove', tellPos, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Mouse Position</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height:400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="mouse-position"></div>
    <form>
        <label>Projection </label>
            <select id="projection">
                <option value="EPSG:4326">EPSG:4326</option>
                <option value="EPSG:3857">EPSG:3857</option>
        </select>
        <label>Precision </label>
        <input id="precision" type="number" min="0" max="12" value="4"/>
        <div id="mouse_posX"></div>
        <div id="mouse_posY"></div>
        <div id='info'></div> 
        <div id='mapInfo'></div> 
    </form>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "mouse-position",
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "6.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "1.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --experimental-scope-hoisting --public-url . index.html"
  }
}
```

As I just recently started with javascript and html programming I have two questions, first if there's anything I'm doing wrong and the second is if there's a way to pass the mouse event to the OpenLayer for example in the **tellPos(p)** function.

**UPDATE**

I now realized the core of my problem. So far a was looking into *mousemove* and *click* events and realized that the OpenLayers library uses the *pointermove* and *pointerdown* instead, and the WxWidgets WebView does not generate the *pointermove* and *pointerdown* events. My question is there's any way to make OpenLayers to use *mousemove* and click instead or to trigger *pointermove* and *pointerdown* from the Javascript code.

any help is greatly appreciated,
kind Regards.

Comment: Try adding the pepjs polyfill as used in the OpenLayers dev version exanples  https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/simple.html and/or changing to the dev version (version 6.4.0 should be released soon)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao (moderator): A moderator is a person who directs a conversation or mediates in a communication, but does not simply delete the communication without giving reasons. Goodbye stackoverflow!

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks for the answer, I added pepjs and also tried the simple example and still not able to receive the mouse events on the ol map with the WxWidgets wevView. Do you know if its is possible to re-direct the mouse events to the map, for example I saw that you can customize the map control and was wondering if that could be the solution to my problem as I´m not sure how close the WxWidgets WebViews are to a browser like chrome. I can receive all the events on the JS program thats why if possible  from the JS program I can trigger a mouse event to the map control.